# After submit the form the checkbox is changed into one or zero for Boolean values in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

After submit the form the checkbox is changed into one or zero for Boolean values in rails but i need checked checkbox after submit the form in rails. How is it possible? please help me how to proceed it.

**batchnotification_controller.rb**

```
   class BatchNotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_batch_notification, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @batch_notification = BatchNotification.new

    @batch_notifications = BatchNotification.all
    @final_count = []
    @calculated_batch_counts = CalculatedBatchCount.all.group_by{|x| x.batch.batch_number  if !x.batch.nil? }
    @a = CalculatedBatchCount.all.group_by{|k| k.batch.serial_id if !k.batch.nil? }

    puts "JAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAIJAI"
    puts @a.inspect
    @calculated_batch_counts.each do |key, values|
      count = values.map{|x| x.finalCount}.length
      h = {"batch_number" => key, "batch_id" => values.map{|x| x.batch.serial_id},"finalcount" => values.map{|x| x.finalCount}.sum(:+)/count}
      @final_count << h
    end
    # => render :json => @final_count and return
    respond_with(@batch_notifications)
  end


  def show
    respond_with(@batch_notification)
  end

  def new
    @batch_notification = BatchNotification.new


    respond_with(@batch_notification)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @batch_notification = BatchNotification.new(batch_notification_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @batch_notification.save
        format.html { redirect_to batch_notifications_path, notice: 'batch_notification was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @batch_notification }
        format.js
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @batch_notification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
        @batch_notification.update(batch_notification_params)

    respond_to do |format|

      if @vehicle.update(vehicle_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @batch_notification, notice: 'batch_notification was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @batch_notification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @batch_notification.destroy
    respond_with(@batch_notification)
  end

  private
    def set_batch_notification
      @batch_notification = BatchNotification.find(params[:id])
    end

    def batch_notification_params
      params.require(:batch_notification).permit(:message,:approved,:finalCount, :batch_id)
    end
end
```

**batch_notification.rb**

```
 class BatchNotification
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :finalCount, type: Float
  field :message, type: String
  field :approved, type: String
  field :batch_id, type: Integer


  belongs_to :batch

end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="batchnote">
                 <thead>
                    <th>Batch</th>
                    <th>Final count</th>
                    <th>Approved</th>
                    <th>Message</th>                        
               </thead>
                <tbody>

                  <tr>
          <% @batch = Batch.find_by(:batch_number => x["batch_number"])%>
                      <% if !@batch.batch_notifications.blank? %>

                       <% @batch.batch_notifications.each do |notification| %>
                        <%= simple_form_for(@batch_notification , remote: true)  do |f| %>
                          <% if notification.approved? %>

                            <td><%= best_in_place notification ,:approved %></td>
                          <% else %>
                            <td ><%= f.check_box :approved, label: false, class: "box-control" , :input_html => {value: @batch_notification.approved}%></td>  
                          <% end %>
                          <% if !notification.message.nil? %>
                            <td><%= best_in_place notification, :message %></td>
                          <% else %>
                          <td id = "<%= @batch.id %>"  class ="notification_view"><%= f.input :message, label: false, placeholder:"message", class: "form-control" , :input_html => {value: @batch_notification.message}%> </td> 
                          <% end %>
                          <%= f.input :batch_id, as: :hidden, :input_html => {value: @batch.id} %>
                        <%end%> 
                      <% end %>
                    <% else %>

                        <%= simple_form_for(@batch_notification , remote: true)  do |f| %>
                            <td ><%= f.check_box :approved, label: false, class: "box-control" , :input_html => {value: @batch_notification.approved}%></td>  
                          <td id = "<%= @batch.id %>"  class ="notification_view"><%= f.input :message, label: false, placeholder:"message", class: "form-control" , :input_html => {value: @batch_notification.message}%> </td> 
                          <%= f.input :batch_id, as: :hidden, :input_html => {value: @batch.id} %>
                    <% end %>

                 <% end %>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                  <% end %>
                </table>
```

After submit the form the checkbox is changed into one or zero for Boolean values in rails but i need checked checkbox after submit the form in rails. How is it possible? please help me how to proceed it.

Note: Here i am creating and showing in same place for records.

Comment: Why is `approved` of string type? Isn't it better to use `Boolean`?

Comment: ok i changed as boolean, but after i submit it. The checkbox checked mark is disabled.